# Insert command in already open CMD through a .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, server, minecraft

I coded a website where my friends can start and close their Minecraft server over PHP. To stop their server, a .bat file kills the process, but normally Minecraft servers will be stopped with the "Stop" command. The Minecraft server is running in a CMD and so my question is:

Is it possible to send a command from a started .bat to a separate, already open CMD so that the already open CMD stop the Server?

Answer (score 3):

You can [send keys](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx) to the console - but eventually you'll need to know the name of the command prompt window. Check the ready to use [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) :

```
call sendKeys.bat "command prompt" "stop{ENTER}"
```

in case the title is just `command prompt`  - it could be different so you need to check this.

Default title:

[image]

Comment: What stands the Command prompt in your example for? The Exact Windowtitle? Because it says everytime that he cannot find the application where i want to input "stop{ENTER}"?

Comment: @LuigiTheHunter  -  `command prompt` is the default title of the console. See my update.

Comment: Ok thanks but its still saying that it cannot find my application.

Comment: wtf windows can be scripted using JAVASCRIPT? This is whole new level of fun! :D

Comment: @LuigiTheHunter - mind tat the the windows title is case sensitive

Comment: @TomášZato  - It is not exactly javascript - it's jscript - a microsoft implementation for WSH - ant it can use a lot of the Windows APIs .It's ecmascript 3 implementation - for ecmascript 6 check the the end of the first posted thread. You can take a look at this [thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5543)  and [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5260) and [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5526) .

Comment: Does no one has any idea?